# Counting the number of rows in the wrong way, how to solve?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

I'm having problem in counting the number of rows that satisfy my conditions

This is a sample of the dataset

```
> head(final_15)
# A tibble: 15 × 4
# Groups:   nquest, nord [15]
   nquest  nord studio  ireg
    <int> <int>  <int> <int>
 1    173     1      5    18
 2   2886     1      5    13
 3   2886     2      6    13
 4   5416     1      3     8
 5   7886     1      5     9
 6  20297     1      3     5
 7  20711     2      2     4
 8  22169     1      2    15
 9  22276     1      5     8
10  22286     1      2     8
11  22286     2      2     8
12  22657     1      7    16
13  22657     2      5    16
14  23490     1      5     5
15  24147     1      7     4
```

I want to know the number of rows that satisfy these 2 conditions

1. `ireg` must have (always) only values 1, 2, 3, 7
2. considering these `ireg` values, I need to know the number of rows when :

   first case: `studio` <= 2

   second case: `studio` >= 3 and `studio` <= 4

   third case: `studio` == 5

   fourth case: `studio` >= 6

I've tried this code, but I get a number of rows that is higher than the entire dataset! probably I'm setting something wrong, but I do not understand where

```
num_rows <- c(length(final_15$studio[final_15$studio <= 2 & final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7]), 
              length(final_15$studio[final_15$studio >= 3 & final_15$studio <= 4 & final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7]),
              length(final_15$studio[final_15$studio == 5 & final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7]),
              length(final_15$studio[final_15$studio >= 6 & final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7]))
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should use `sum` rather than `length` on a logical vector. See the difference between `length(c(T, F, T, F))` and `sum(c(T, F, T, F))`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai i've tried to use `sum`, but it sums the value of the rows. I need to count them instead

Comment: ok @DarrenTsai I've tried `sum(final_15$studio <= 2 & final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7)` but I've get the same exact result

Comment: You need `()` around the "or" statement: `sum(final_15$studio <= 2 & (final_15$ireg <= 3 | final_15$ireg == 7))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with dplyr that's a bit more lengthy but hopefully nice and clear. Also included a modified version of your printed data for other answerers to use - instead of providing head(), in future provide something like I've done here so people don't have to type out your data manually.

```
dataset <- tibble(nquest = c(173,2886,2886,5416,7886,20297,20711,22169,22276,22286),
                  nord = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1),
                  studio = c(5,5,6,3,5,3,2,2,5,2),
                  ireg = c(1,1,2,3,5,7,7,2,4,1))

data.flt <- dataset %>% 
  filter(ireg %in% c(1,2,3,7))

data.flt

first.case <- nrow(filter(data.flt, studio <= 2))
second.case <- nrow(filter(data.flt, studio >= 3, studio <= 4))
third.case <- nrow(filter(data.flt, studio == 5))
fourth.case <- nrow(filter(data.flt, studio >= 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

The data snippet you've given us doesn't have *any* of the specified `ireg` values in it, so it's not very useful for testing ...

I would do this as follows:

```r
dds <- subset(your_data, ireg %in% c(1, 2, 3, 7))$studio
table(cut(dds$studio, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 5, Inf))
```

(`cut` converts a numeric variable into a factor; the intervals are closed on the right by default, i.e. the first category in the example above will have values of `0 < studio <= 2`)

If you wanted to wrap this up in a function that selected values of `var1` in `include_vals` and then tabulated variable `var2` according to breakpoints `brk` you could do:

```r
tab_fun <- function(data, 
                    var1 = "ireg", 
                    include_vals = c(1, 2, 3, 7),
                    var2 = "studio",
                    brk = c(2, 4, 5) ##internal only
           ) {
   table(cut(dds[data[[var1]] %in% include_vals, var2],    
            breaks = c(0, brk, Inf)))
}
```

Comment: hi @BenBolker , thank for the answer. Is there a way to do that withoust subseting the dataset? I need to set thins kind of procedure for other variables , hence I will get too many smaller datasets

Answer (score 1):

##### Example data

```r
set.seed(123)

final_15 <- data.frame(
  ireg = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
  studio = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

A `dplyr` solution with `count()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

final_15 %>%
  filter(ireg %in% c(1, 2, 3, 7)) %>%
  count(grp = cut(studio, c(-Inf, 2, 4, 5, Inf), c("<=2", "3-4", "5", ">=6")))

#   grp  n
# 1 <=2  1
# 2 3-4  5
# 3   5  4
# 4 >=6 27
```